# How to deal with floated elements?

Tags: html, css

If there are floated elements in a parent element, they parent element looses its shape or has no height. How to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to that is using **[clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)** class.

Answer (score 1):

On the parent, do a:

```
 style="overflow: auto"
```

Comment: @Faisal `overflow: visible` has problems in IE. Auto should not. Anyway, clearfix is a good idea as well.

Comment: I just tried with overflow auto, did not work in IE6 and when i added zoom:1px then it worked fine as suggested by vermutt. I could show my code if you say, it did not work in IE6. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to wrap floated elements with a block that has a clearfix hack applied. Read more here:
http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

For IE<7 you would also use zoom:1;