# Styling Container background?

Tags: css, background-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377889/how-to-deal-with-floated-elements)

I have a probably basic html css styling question:

If I have:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column"> </div>
<div class="column"> </div>
<div class="column"> </div>
</div>
```

Then... when I style the columns with a background-color they get the background color.

BUT the container somehow does not stretch until the bottom of the content: it only fills content with a background color or any other property if I put "content" in it e.g.:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column"> </div>
<div class="column"> </div>
<div class="column"> </div>
one line of background color
</div>
```

Now I get one line behind the whole thing that is "green" while I want it to stretch the complete thing.

Why does the container not know where the bottom is? Is there anything I can do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've floated the inner `div`s, you'll need to add `overflow: auto` to the container element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). I usually just `overflow:hidden` the container.